# How to set default page, but keep URL extension?

Tags: htaccess

I am trying to set {mydomain}/forum to be the default URL that people are brought to when they go to {mydomain}. I have this working, as in my .htaccess I wrote `DirectoryIndex index.php?route=/forum/` (this is the less simplified version of /forum, both work. just putting "forum" didn't work so I replaced it with this). The problem is that it doesn't redirect them to /forum, it just keeps them on /. It shows the right page, but doesn't have /forum in the URL.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Redirecting away from the root URL isn't common practice because it doesn't look good.  Why do you want to do it?

Comment: Is `/forum` a physical subdirectory? Do you have any other directives or any other `.htaccess` files?

Comment: @StephenOstermiller the problem is if they go to the website, they see {mydomain}. then if they go somewhere else and then click the link to Forum, they see {mydomain}/forum. i don't like that the same page can show two URLs like that

Comment: I would choose the simpler URL as the canonical and eliminate the `/forum` URL instead.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller I am using a forum builder and to be honest I'm not really sure how, other than adding a `header(Location:{mydomain});` perhaps.

Answer (score 1):

I don't normally like to redirect away from the root but if that is your goal try this.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^$ /forum [L]
```

---

[This Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/990392/htaccess-rewrite-to-redirect-root-url-to-subdirectory) on StackOverflow should get you what you need.